# How do I fix issues im having with WhatsApp camera, video calling and now the camera in general?

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger, camera, samsung-apps

My Son has a Samsung A04 and has recently out the blue getting a **whatsapp error that states: Whatsapp was unable to start the camera. if you continue to experience issues with the camera, please restart your device.**
Cool so i did just that.. Restart.. try video call again, same issue.

Next uninstall Whatsapp, restart phone, reinstall whatsapp, do the setup again, try to video call, and it worked. directly after the test video call he tries to video call his mom and same error came up again.

now after trying to search for a fix another system error came up the reads: **com.sec.Android.app.camerasaver keeps stopping.**

I have cleared the cache of both camera and whatsapp apps, and whatsapp has all the permissions it possibly can get.
But now when im trying to open the camera app that comes with the phone it also says: **couldnt open camera, Try Again**

**Please Help!!!!**

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: What about other apps do they can work with the cameras? BTW you can easily make screenshots using the Android built in screenshot function. No need to make photos of the screen.

Comment: I am aware of taking screenshot thank you, it was just easier at that moment to take pictures lol. Don't have any other apps installed that uses the camera. But that the main camera app doesn't want to work I think is the main concern

Comment: Every Android device comes wit pre-installed camera app which can make photos and videos.

Comment: Bro I know.... and it's not working like I said above... and I'm not finding fix for it

Comment: First thing to try is to reset the phone (after assuring everything that needs to be kept is backed up), not reinstall Whatsapp which error message is anything but a symptom.

Comment: You said you checked permissions?  What about the `camera access` quick tile toggle state?  Have you tried running QC/engineering mode to test the camera?